# Set variable from multiple threads without guards depending on data bus

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, x86-64

I am using c++ multi threading on x64. I would like to understand data bus better. I want to understand what would happen if I try to set variable from 2 threads without any guard (no mutex, CV, semaphore, and no atomic). What is dependent from data bus.
For example if I have variable:

```
 int32_t i;
```

if I set variable in different threads:
thread 1:

```
  i =0x11223344;
```

thread 2:

```
  i =0x44332211;
```

As I know for x64 data bus is 64 bits. So variable *i* can be set in 1 instruction. I know it depends on compiler. I know cache also have influence. I would like to know only interaction with data-bus (with no cache). My question is what would be behavior depending on data bus width(8, 16, 32 bit). What would be the value of *i*?

Comment: There's nothing to understand. In the 1400+ pages that make up the current C++ standard, there's no mention of anything that's described as a "data bus".

Comment: C++ just says this is undefined behavior, so that doesn't help in answering the question. You would need to compile the program into assembly and then look up what those assembly instructions do to figure out what the code does (which obviously changes depending on compiler flags and other things). You should post the assembly code so that an answer is at least possible.

Comment: my question is if the set is in one instruction are both will be atomic.

Comment: Simple answer: No. The behavior is undefined as far as C++ is concerned. Notice that atomicity is actually not the biggest issue here, but memory ordering. An atomic write is useless if you don't know when it becomes visible to the other core.

Comment: @ComicSansMS would you mind to give details or at least reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfortunate answer is that there is no clear answer to your question.

Let's step away from C++ for a moment here: What you want to do is perform an unsynchronized concurrent write. The guarantees that you can give with regards to what the result of such an operation would be vary greatly, depending on a number of factors. Of course, the target architecture plays a major role. A machine with a strong memory model like x86 might be more forgiving here than, say a PowerPC or ARM machine. But it doesn't end here. Alignment could play a crucial role, as could the specific memory configuration on the machine that you are running on (think NUMA architectures). So there is just no one-size fits all answer. It all depends very delicately on the circumstances, and even if the circumstances are known exactly, the answer you are often left with is: We simply can't tell, it could be anything in the end (including a number that appears out-of-thin-air, that is, a value that was not written by either of the concurrent write operations), because that's simply how the hardware was built.

Because of this, it simply does not make sense to discuss this question on such a high-level. As far as x86 is concerned, there are some guarantees given by the instruction set architecture. Feel free to browse the relevant sections of [the manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) yourself. But you have no way of accessing those guarantees from within a higher level-language if you are using thread-unaware memory accesses. Because the behavior is undefined, the compiler is allowed to perform any number of optimizations that can mess up the generated code in arbitrary ways, but are still consistent with what you expressed in code. Because your code is unaware of concurrency (by definition, as you are using unsynchronized access), the compiler has every right to do this.

So the only way out is to use proper synchronization, for example locks or atomics. They give certain guarantees on both the language level (disallowing certain compiler optimizations) and ensure that those guarantees are followed all the way down to the hardware (by inserting the necessary synchronization instructions in the generated machine code). Only if you have this full chain of guarantees from the high-level language down to the very silicon that makes up the hardware can you do proper multi-threaded programming. Remove any single link from the chain and the whole thing collapses.

Comment: Yes you are right for the high level. I was thinking that at the and should the value should be one of the two values or byte mix like (0x11222211). Such question maybe will be better to be ask on assembly level or maybe to just to hardware level. My question was for simple curiosity. Thanks for details.I will read dew things from the manual.

Comment: @Vladimir - On an x64 a properly aligned integer value is always written all at once, so it will not get "mixed". However, unless it is an `atomic<int>` there is no real guarantee that it is written to memory at all. Also, the compiler might take advantage of the hardware features and use the same instructions to read an write atomic values as it does for "normal" values. It only has to assure it is done at the proper time.